# Mapping the key value in assoc array base on its union?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Array mapping?

I have

```
$A= array("A1"=>array("x"=>1,"b"=>2,"d"=>3,"s"=>8),
          "A2"=>array("a"=>4,"b"=>3,"c"=>2,"d"=>1)
          );
```

OUTPUT(HTML):

```
   | a |  b  |  c | d | x | s
------------------------------
A1 | 0 |  2  |  0 | 3 | 1 | 8
A2 | 4 |  3  |  2 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

Anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: What do you want to ouput? An HTML table? Something else. You have to give some more info to enable us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the keys

```
$keys = array_unique(array_merge (array_keys($A['A1']), array_keys($A['A2'])));
```

Then create the output

```
echo " | ";
echo implode(' | ', $keys) . "\n";

echo "\n";
foreach ($A as $name => $oneA) {
  echo "$name ";
  foreach ($keys as $key) echo "| ". (isset($oneA[$key]) ? $oneA[$key] : 0);
  echo "\n";
}
```

or as html-table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php implode('</td><td>', $keys);</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($A as $name => $oneA) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <?php foreach ($keys as $key): ?>
      <td><?php echo isset($oneA[$key]) ? $oneA[$key] : 0; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

You may sort the keys before and format the output. Its just the short form.

Comment: Ive added it, but usually you should be able to create html-tables yourself ;) However, I dont promise its completely error-free ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, collect all the keys in the inner arrays:

```
$keys = array_keys(
    array_reduce($A, function ($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }, array()));
sort($keys);
```

The print the headers, and finally iterate over the lines and, for each line, over the keys:

```
foreach ($A as $lineKey => $lineValue) {
    //TODO: print $lineKey;
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        //TODO: print $lineValue[$k]; or 0
    }
}
```