# Callback Function Fatal Error: Unsupported operand types in

Tags: php

```
<?php
$A= array("A1"=>array("x"=>1,"b"=>2,"d"=>3,"s"=>8),
          "A2"=>array("a"=>4,"b"=>3,"c"=>2,"d"=>1)
          );
function callback($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }


$keys = array_keys(array_reduce($A, "callback", array()));
sort($keys);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($keys);
echo '</pre>';
```

What am I wrong here?Because I got message:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in .... in line

Comment: Because `$a` and `$b` are different of types `$b` is an array and `$a` is integer 0 in first iteration

Comment: Do you know how can I fixed the problems?

Comment: I don't know, what you want to achieve, but at least your code produces no error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce, I dont get an error, if I execute your code. But it seems, that you just want to get the unique keys.

```
$keys = array_unique(array_merge (array_keys($A['A1']), array_keys($A['A2'])));
```

Comment: yes,my idea .in this question.,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466716/mapping-the-key-value-in-assoc-array-base-on-its-union